# Vue.js Import mixin does not import in app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-mixin

> The requested module './clienteMixin.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

Mixin

```
export const myMixin = {
    data() {
        return {
            loading: false,
        }
    }
}
```

Vue App

```
import myMixin from './clienteMixin.js'

var app = new Vue({
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    el: '#app',
    components:{},
    mixins: [myMixin],
    data() {
        return {
            
        }
    },
    methods: {
    
    },
    mounted () {
    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your export to use the `default` export:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
    }
  },
}
```

This will fix the import issue.  If you want your mixin to be a [global mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin), use [`Vue.mixin`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-mixin):

```js
import myMixin from './clienteMixin.js'

Vue.mixin(myMixin);

const app = new Vue({
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    el: '#app',
    components:{},
    data() {
      return {
      }
    },
    methods: {
    },
    mounted () { 
    }
});
```